# Photon number statistics of a displaced thermal state

Tags: quantum-optics

What I am looking for is the possibility of detecting $n$ photon in a displaced thermal state

> $\langle n|\rho_{dts}|n\rangle$
>
> $\rho_{DTS} = D(\alpha)\rho_{TS} D(-\alpha)$

where $\rho_{TS}$ is a thermal state with mean photon number $B$ and $D(\alpha)$ is the displacement operator.

I have already found an analytical expression for the first 4 term:

> $\langle n|\rho_{dts}|n\rangle = exp(-\alpha^2/(B+1))P_n$

Where $P_0$ to $P_3$ could be found in this post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844741/try-to-guess-a-closed-form-expression

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to single mode non-interacting oscillator.

$\textbf{Hint :}$ Define $\mathbb{G}[\lambda_{}^{}]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e_{}^{i\lambda n}\langle n|\rho_{}^{}| n\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\langle n|e_{}^{i\lambda a_{}^{\dagger}a_{}^{}}\rho_{}^{}| n\rangle=\textbf{Tr}[e_{}^{i \lambda a_{}^{\dagger}a_{}^{}} \rho_{}^{}]$.

Now $\mathbb{G}[\lambda_{}^{}]$ can be easily evaluated by taking trace in coherent state basis for the choice $\rho_{}^{}=\rho_{DTS}^{}$. (you will encounter only gaussian integrals).

$\langle n|\rho_{DTS}^{}|n\rangle$ can be generated as Fourier expansion coefficients or by taylor expanding $\mathbb{G}[-i\log(s)]$ in $s$.

$\textbf{Note :}$ See this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402321).

Comment: Nice trick. I think the trace could also easily be calculated using the Wigner functions. Then the result could be easily generalized to photon number statistics of any Gaussian state.

Comment: Have you actually obtained a closed-form expression yet?

Comment: As its an old post, I can't recollect. If you want I can provide it soon.

Comment: Would be great. I am trying to work it out myself, but it's hairy.